# How to handle user input with a mixture of HTML and punctuation?

Tags: php, mysql, user-input, sanitization

I have a form field that includes a mixture of HTML and text. **I want users to be able to use basic HTML** and punctuation.

Currently I am using **mysql_real_escape_string** and **preg_replace** to sanitise the data and insert it into the database. My understanding is that preg_replace is the best way to strip any characters that are not in a white list of allowed characters and that mysql_real_escape_string protects from SQL injection.

```
//How I collect and sanitise the data...
$var=mysql_real_escape_string(
 preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9-?!$#@()\"'.:;\\@,_ =\/<> ]/",'',$_POST['var'])
);
```

However, it keeps breaking when the hash character is used.

My questions are:

1) Is there a more efficient way to do this?

2) If this is the best way, what am I doing wrong?

The characters that I need to allow are: all alphanumeric characters and:

**? ! @ # $ % & ( ) - . , : ; ' " < > / + =**

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since many non-alphanumeric characters have special meanings in a regex, you should escape all of them.  So

```
preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9-?!$#@()\"'.:;\\@,_ =\/<> ]/",'',$_POST['var'])
```

becomes (there are a few that probably don't need escaping, but it doesn't hurt)

```
preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9-\?\!\$\#\@\(\)\"\'\.\:\;\\@\,\_ \=\/\<\> ]/",'',$_POST['var'])
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm hesitant to use strip_tags if it is not reliable.

Answer (score 4):

Why not just use strip_tags() and limit it to the tags you need?

```
strip_tags ($str,"<br>")
```

You could then do other "sanitation" that is not quite as invasive.

Comment: should be noted that strip_tags, while nice when it works, is not reliable. http://ca.php.net/strip_tags